# Is it possible to build AirPlay like functionality for Google TV?

Tags: google-tv

I know Anymote protocol lets iOS / Android mobile devices to talk to Google TV. I was wondering if I can use Fling events to pass in a remote video URL and ask Google TV to invoke Media Player to playback that URL?

---

I am following GoogleTV Pairing Protocol Guidelines documented here,

http://code.google.com/tv/remote/docs/pairing.html

and also suggested by a member, I am using proto-buf-objc

http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers project 
to create my objective-c message classes from .proto file.

I could also able to find "_anymote._tcp" service provided by GoogleTV 
Pairing Protocol server and got IP/port number after resolving the 
service.

I created an SSL connection as described in the Pairing Protocol 
documentation for sending and receiving messages.

Then I constructed a PairingRequest, wrapped that in OuterMessage and 
used writeToCodedOutputStream method to send that to my open 
NSOutputStream to GoogleTV.

I also got a response back on my NSInputStream and I am trying to 
parse it into an OuterMessage using [OuterMessage 
parseFromData:_data_received] but that throws an exception saying " 
exception 'InvalidProtocolBuffer', reason: ''" ". I am not whats going 
wrong here.

Does anyone at Google has any recommendations on what might be going 
wrong? Also any code example or iOS library of Paring protocol 
would be very helpful. I just want to enable Airplay like 
functionality for GoogleTV in my app. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For [Remotes](http://code.google.com/tv/remote/) for Google TV, you would have to implement [Anymote](http://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/) on iOS.  It shouldn't be too difficult - [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-objc/) already exist for it.  Android is easier w/ [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/).

And it's fairly easy to Fling a URL.